# harpoon as the pang game in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using Scene2D.
This is my Shoot Actor

```
public class ActorDisparo extends Actor {

private TextureRegion textureDisparo = new TextureRegion();
private World world;
public static Body body;
//private Fixture fixture;
private FixtureDef fdef;
private String userData;
private float anchoDisparo, altoDisparo;
private float positionX,positionY;
private static float porcentajeDeancho = 0,anchoMediano = 0, anchoPequeno = 0, anchoDiminuto = 0;
private TextureRegion arponRegion = new TextureRegion();

public ActorDisparo(World world, TextureRegion disparo, Vector2 position, float anchoDisparo, float altoDisparo, float fuerzaX, float fuerzaY, String userData){
    this.textureDisparo = disparo;
    this.world = world;
    this.anchoDisparo = anchoDisparo;
    this.altoDisparo = altoDisparo;
    this.userData = userData;

    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(position);
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    PolygonShape shapeDisparo = new PolygonShape();
    shapeDisparo.setAsBox((anchoDisparo/2)/2,altoDisparo/2);

    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    fdef.shape = shapeDisparo;
    //fdef.restitution = 0.70f;

    fdef.filter.categoryBits = BolasGame.DISPARO_BIT;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = BolasGame.BOLAROJA_BIT |
                           BolasGame.TECHO_BIT;

    body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(userData);
    shapeDisparo.dispose();
    body.setGravityScale(0f);
    body.applyLinearImpulse(fuerzaX,fuerzaY,position.x,position.y,true);

    setSize( anchoDisparo *BolasGame.MetrosAPixels ,altoDisparo*BolasGame.MetrosAPixels);

    //setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public float getPositionX() {
    return getPositionX();
}

public float getPositionY() {
    return getPositionY();
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    setPosition( (body.getPosition().x * BolasGame.MetrosAPixels) - getWidth()/2, (body.getPosition().y * BolasGame.MetrosAPixels) - getHeight()/2);
    batch.draw(textureDisparo,getX(),getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
}

public void detach(){
        world.destroyBody(body);
        remove();
}

}
```

and this is the call to shoot class

```
 if(Gdx.input.justTouched() && hasdisparado == false){
        hasdisparado =true;
        touch = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);

        stage.getCamera().unproject(touch);
        arponRegion = new TextureRegion(textureDisparo, 0, 0, 20, 40);

        actorDisparo = new ActorDisparo(world,arponRegion,new Vector2(touch.x/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels,touch.y/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels ),20/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels,40/BolasGame.MetrosAPixels,0,2f,BolasGame.USERDATA_DISPARO);
        stage.addActor(actorDisparo);
    }
```

this creates a shot like a bullet but I need since I touched the screen until it is destroyed is continuous like the harpoon of game pang

the textureregion the charge of a texture whose dimensions are 446x20

```
textureDisparo = new Texture("gfx/disparo.png");
```

I have no idea how to do this because you have to repeat the image and body in box2d for collisions.
I totally lost

if someone can give me an idea would appreciate
Thank you
(Sorry for my English, I'm learning now)

Comment: "this creates a shot like a bullet but I need `..........` since I touched the screen until it is destroyed is continuous like the harpoon of game pang". You need what? And elaborate on the pang Harpoon please.

Comment: I need a shot as the game pang. Not is a simple shot is a continuous shot since you press the screen until it collides with the ceiling or objects. Thank you

Comment: I need this harpoon shoot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHgdXKQDfsE but I do not know how to do it